# Java Localized Calendar

Tags: java, internationalization, calendar

I'm developing an internationalized application, in which I need to dynamically change my calendar without changing the code. As you know, Calendar.getInstance() returns a Gregorian calendar, how can I use a different calendar when I call Calendar.getInstance(). So, I dynamically change my localized calendar without changing the code.

Best

Answer (score 2):

Use the [factory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.TimeZone,%20java.util.Locale%29) to do so:

```
public static Calendar getInstance(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different calendar system (it is really hard to tell what you are up to), then [ICU4J Project](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/) is your friend.
It contains several different calendar systems (see [com.ibm.icu.util](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/package-summary.html) package).

To use different calendar system, just instantiate Calendar with valid [ULocale](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/ULocale.html) and you are all done:

```
// valid for desktop applications, for web you'd do it differently
ULocale arabicLocale = new ULocale("ar_SA@calendar=islamic");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(arabicLocale);
```

Unfortunately, I can help it but it seems that you would have to assign calendar system through specific ULocale identifier. I don't know why they haven't set proper defaults... Anyway...

ICU also provides its own implementation of [DateFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DateFormat.html) as well as [TimeZone](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/TimeZone.html) and I am afraid that this is what you should use to format Calendar. Fortunately their implementation accepts `Calendar`, so it is actually easier to use:

```
TimeZone currentTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
    DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, arabicLocale);
formatter.setTimeZone(currentTimeZone);
String formattedDateTime = formatter.format(calendar);
```